# Plot sample with different colors in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried the following code to plot a set of samples over a 2D plane.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# some code generating x and y

matplotlib.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, 'o')
ax.set_title('Using hypen instead of unicode minus')
plt.show()
```

I would like to provide a list of values (where each values ranges from 0 to k-1), so that each sample is displayed with the corresponding color. How would I need to modify the code above?

Comment: I don't see how the samples are differentiated - does each point plotted have a third value associated, which you want to relate to a `colormap`; or can you define samples based on the `(x,y)` location?

Comment: I have a list of numbers, say 'color', which is available. Each data point is associated with the corresponding number. For example, if 'colors' is the list of values, colors[0] is the color of x[0]

Comment: matplotlib is there before you! `ax.scatter(x,y,c=colors, 'o')`

(see gallery example http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_demo2.html

which is plotting *four* values for every point: x, y, color, size